# SQL - Selecting only columns containing sum(data)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This are few records that I want to have sum of but excluding columns with NULL values:

```
ID  val1  val2  val3
 1          1     2
 2          0     3
 3          2     4
```

select 
  sum(val1),
  sum(val2),
  sum(val3)
from table
will result in:

```
val1  val2  val3
        3     9
```

but I would prefer to see:

```
val2  val3
  3     9
```

Is there anyway to achive that in SQL or PL/SQL?

kind regards

Comment: You have to use PL/SQL and a dynamic query (`execute immediate`).  SQL queries return a *fixed* set of columns.  If you want dynamic numbers of columns, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: This going to be extremely difficult to do and slow, you need to select all the data in order to build the query to select the data, then use execute immediate to select the data again. Not only that it's a very bad idea as the format of the result changes on each execution, this virtually always leads to mus-interpretation and confusion. Also what would be the result is a column is null in one row but another. I.E it contained the row 4,1,null,7.

Comment: Belayer, I see your concerns. Altho my problem is even worse as after having not null columns sumerized, I have to calculate an average of the sums... and after some another computations propagate it back... I know I am stretching possibilities of SQL/plSQL here...

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID       VAL1       VAL2       VAL3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1                     1          2
         2                     0          3
         3                     2          4
```

In my opinion, this is just fine:

```
SQL> select sum(val1), sum(val2), sum(val3) from test;

 SUM(VAL1)  SUM(VAL2)  SUM(VAL3)
---------- ---------- ----------
                    3          9

SQL>
```

Why? Because what you *prefer* requires some programming and that doesn't have to be simple. Your example is simple, so something like this is easy as there are 6 possible combinations:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return sys_refcursor
  2  is
  3    l_sum1 number;
  4    l_sum2 number;
  5    l_sum3 number;
  6    rc     sys_refcursor;
  7  begin
  8     select sum(val1), sum(val2), sum(val3)
  9       into l_sum1   , l_sum2   , l_sum3
 10     from test;
 11
 12     if l_sum1 is null and l_sum2 is null and l_sum3 is null then
 13        open rc for select null from dual;
 14     elsif l_sum1 is null and l_sum2 is null then
 15        open rc for select l_sum3 from dual;
 16     elsif l_sum1 is null and l_sum3 is null then
 17        open rc for select l_sum2 from dual;
 18     elsif l_sum2 is null and l_sum3 is null then
 19        open rc for select l_sum1 from dual;
 20     elsif l_sum1 is null then
 21        open rc for select l_sum2, l_sum3 from dual;
 22     elsif l_sum2 is null then
 23        open rc for select l_sum1, l_sum3 from dual;
 24     elsif l_sum3 is null then
 25        open rc for select l_sum1, l_sum2 from dual;
 26     end if;
 27     return rc;
 28  end;
 29  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

       :B2        :B1
---------- ----------
         3          9

SQL> update test set val3 = null;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

       :B1
----------
         3
```

In a more complex situation, with more columns, such an approach would be close to *suicide* so you'd have to do that differently, use dynamic SQL which makes things not that easy, so the question is: is it worth it? I don't think so.

Comment: Dear Littlefoot, this path is what I had in mind but my problem in RL has 30 columns... Your approach is what I had in mind but quickly realized it is not that efficient nor effective. Altho thank You for for your input.

Comment: Right; as you were already told, this isn't simple at all. You're welcome.